# Selecting columns with fixed pattern at beginning and end of name, and variable middle part

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to `select` data frame columns that have a certain pattern at the beginning and the end of their names, and one out of several possible values in the middle. This is what works, but I find the double use of `intersect` not very elegant.

```
df <- data.frame(var1_one_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var1_two_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var1_three_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var1_four_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var2_one_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var1_one_fac = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))

var_middle <- c("one|two|three")

df %>% select(intersect(starts_with("var1_"),
                        intersect(matches(var_middle),
                                  ends_with("_num")))) %>% names()

[1] "var1_one_num"   "var1_two_num"   "var1_three_num"
```

I suspect there is smarter way with `any of` or similar, but I could not get round it.

Comment: You can probably use `df %>%
 select(matches("^var1_(one|two|three)_.*num$"))`.

Comment: I like this solution - do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer by @tmfmnk which I suggested he post, but he hasn't so far. Since I wanted to something in `dplyr`, this is what I was looking for:

```
df %>% select(matches("^var1_(one|two|three)_.*num$"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you only need the column names - you can use regular expressions to achieve this:

```
> grep(pattern = '^var1.*(one|two|three).*num$', x = colnames(df), value = T)
[1] "var1_one_num"   "var1_two_num"   "var1_three_num"
```

the `^` sign indicates the string must begin with that pattern, the `$` indicates the what the string must end with. The round bracket with `|` separator indicates that any of these values are acceptable.

To get column values:

```
> df[, grep(pattern = '^var1.*(one|two|three).*num$', x = colnames(df), value = T)]
   var1_one_num var1_two_num var1_three_num
1             9            1              7
2             2           10              4
3             2            9              1
4             1            5              4
5             4            9             10
6             6            8              8
7             9            5              7
8             6            2              6
9             5            3              5
10            1            1              7
```

If you're unfamiliar with regex, here's a good link to learn more: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html

Hope this is helpful!